# How to select this attribute with a specific class - jquery

Tags: jquery, selection

I have jquery that looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".lmls").click(function(){
        var groupid = $('span#gid').attr('value');
        $("#otherpaths"+groupid).toggle();
        // alert(groupid);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to show/hide based on the class `.lmls` :

```
    <div class="lmls">
    <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
    </div>

<div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths5" style="">
    <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="5"></span>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
        <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
            <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
            <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
        </div>
</div>

    <div class="lmls">
    <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
    </div>

<div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths6" style="">
    <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="6"></span>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
        <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
            <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
            <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
        </div>
</div>
```

This works by the value of `span` tag included in each `.otherpaths` .
These values are repeated multiple times in a single page.

The problem is, when I click on one of my `.lmls` classes it doesn't show/hide the right `.lmls` class , it just shows the first - since my second line of my `js` is just looking for `.lmls`, and `.lmls` occurs multiple times in the same page.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs in your page?

Comment: Please see further comments above.

Comment: Please, add a code snippet.

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: I was trying to base it off of the [value] attribute of <span> tag - how can i modify my jquery to do so?

Comment: What do you want to hide, the whole `.lmls` class that's been clicked?

Comment: @charliebrownie - no,  the .otherpaths content when .lmls is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lmls').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next(".otherpaths").toggle();  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lmls">
  <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
</div>

<div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths5" style="">
  <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="5"></span>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
    <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
    <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
    <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lmls">
  <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
</div>

<div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths6" style="">
  <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="6"></span>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
    <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
    <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
    <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

or if you are open to changing the structure of your html a bit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lmls').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.section').find('.otherpaths').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="lmls">
    <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
  </div>

  <div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths5" style="display:none;">
    <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="5"></span>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
      <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
      <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
      <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div class="lmls">
    <img src="img/pathway_icon.png" align="center" width="40px" height="40px"> Leads to other pathways
  </div>

  <div class="otherpaths" id="otherpaths5" style="display:none;">
    <span style="display: none;" id="gid" value="5"></span>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath1">
      <a href="path1.php">Link1</a> </div>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath2">
      <a href="path2.php">Link2</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="grouppath" id="grouppath3">
      <a href="path3" target="_blank">Link3</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CodeTalk what version of jQuery are you using

Comment: Your issue was the quotes for next() method. Need " - not '

Comment: @CodeTalk thanks, i also did it a way where you dont have to change the structure of your html at all (the first way)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

```
$( ".lmls" ).click(function(){
    $( this ).find( '.otherpaths' ).toggle();
});
```

of course, when Document is ready!

Have a look at the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq0nx5x8/2/).